# Select priorizado e ordenado por campo

Tags: php, sql

[image: BASE DE DADOS]

Bom tenho uma tabela de programação de horarios e preciso exibir o locutor que esta ao vivo no momento, estou pegando via php as datas e jogando no select porem varias vezes sai ou desordenado ou nao sai ao certo vou tentar resumir o que tenho para facilitar. Lembrando que pode ter o mesmo horario em dias diferentes, portanto o ORDER BY FIELD dara prioridade para $hoje.

```
 <?php
 $diasemana = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terca', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado');
 $data = date('Y-m-d');
 $diasemana_numero = date('w', strtotime($data));
 $hoje = $diasemana[$diasemana_numero];

 $hora = date("H");
 $minuto = date("i");
 $horaatual = $hora."h".$minuto;
 try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM programacao WHERE horafinal >= '$horaatual' ORDER BY FIELD(dias,'$hoje','De Segunda a Sexta','De Segunda a Sabado'), horafinal ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Não sei se esta na lógica ou na programação mesmo o erro, se caso alguém tiver alguma ideia melhor também aceito sugestões.

Comment: Por favor, evite usar caixa alta no titulo da pergunta, a não ser que seja realmente necessário(para siglas, etc).

Comment: Qual o "type" destas colunas horainicial e horafinal ? Sendo numérica vc poderia usar um BETWEEN da hora corrente para saber o que está (ou deveria) no ar.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time

Comment: Esta em vachar os campos eu poderia alterar para datetime mais gostaria de saber como ordenar mesmo sendo texto.